# How to use a python function from another module

Tags: python, import, module

I trying to import a module and use a function from that module in my current python file.

I run the nosetests on the parser_tests.py file but it fails with "name 'parse_subject' not defined"

e.g its not finding the parse_subject function which is clearly defined in the parsrer.py file

This is the parsrer file:

```
def peek(word_list):
if word_list:
    word = word_list[0]
    return word[0]
else:
    return None

#Confirms that the expected word is the right type,
```

def match(word_list, expecting):
    if word_list:
        word = word_list.pop(0)

```
    if word[0] == expecting:
        return word
    else:
        return None
else:
    return None
```

def skip(word_list, word_type):
    while peek(word_list) == word_type:
        match(word_list, word_type)

def parse_verb(word_list):
    skip(word_list, 'stop')

```
if peek(word_list) == 'verb':
    return match(word_list, 'verb')
else:
    raise ParserError("Expected a verb next.")
```

def parse_object(word_list):
    skip(word_list, 'stop')
    next_word = peek(word_list)

```
if next_word == 'noun':
    return match(word_list, 'noun')
elif next_word == 'direction':
    return match(word_list, 'direction')
else:
    raise ParserError("Expected a noun or direction next.")
```

def parse_subject(word_list):
    skip(word_list, 'stop')
    next_word = peek(word_list)

```
if next_word == 'noun':
    return match(word_list, 'noun')
elif next_word == 'verb':
    return ('noun', 'player')
else:
    raise ParserError("Expected a verb next.")
```

def parse_sentence(word_list):
    subj = parse_subject(word_list)
    verb = parse_verb(word_list)
    obj = parse_object(word_list)

```
return Sentence(subj, verb, obj)
```

This is my tests file

```
from nose.tools import *
```

from nose.tools import assert_equals
import sys
sys.path.append("h:/projects/projectx48/ex48")

import parsrer

def test_subject(): 
    word_list = [('noun', 'bear'), ('verb', 'eat'), ('stop', 'the'), ('noun', 'honey')]
    assert_equals(parse_subject(word_list), ('noun','bear'))

Comment: can you post how are u importing it ?

Answer (score 0):

## Import Module

You can either import the whole module or you can specifically import that specific function using **from an example keyword**.

For example:

```
from parser_tests import parse_subject

# and then you can invoke the function. 

parse_subject()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know exactly how to diagnose your issue without seeing your code, but here's my best guess as to what might help.

First, [`parser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html) is already a builtin module in Python, so you should consider a different name for your **parser.py** file.

Second, you should make sure that the path to the directory in which your **parser.py** file resides can be found in `sys.path`.  You can check this yourself by running this snippet from your **current Python file**:

```
import sys

for line in sys.path:
    print line
```

If the directory in which `parser.py` is found is *not* included in your `path`, you can append that path to `sys.path`, like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/your/module")
```

Finally, you should make sure that you are importing your function properly in your **current Python file**, like this:

```
from parser import parser_subject
```

Comment: Ive followed your clear steps, and changed file name from parser to parsrer - only thing is it says " no module named parsrer " now

Comment: Does it matter which directory I run nosetests from when my PYTHONPATH is set to '.'

Comment: If you are able to edit your question to include the relevant parts of your updated code, that would make it much easier to diagnose @nathanH05

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that there is already a built in function called parser. I am calling one of my locally created parser.py file that I put together instead.